# Python append to list overriding all other elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I have this function:

```
def create_blank_curl_params(urls):
    curl_params_list = []
    for url in urls:
        curl_params = CurlParameters
        curl_params.url = url
        curl_params_list.append(curl_params)

    numbers = []
    for number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        new_number = number
        numbers.append(new_number)

    return curl_params_list
```

where CurlParameters is just an object. Now my numbers list (for reference) looks great, it shows [1,2,3,4,5]. However, my curl_params_list is just 5 repeating elements. It's as though each time it appends(curl_params) it replaces everything else, how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to create a new `CurlParameters` object each time. You're re-writing the url.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would create a new object. If you can only use `CurlParameters` object, you need to create a new copy of it:

```
import copy
def create_blank_curl_params(urls):
    curl_params_list = []
    for url in urls:
        curl_params = copy.deepcopy(CurlParameters)
        curl_params.url = url
        curl_params_list.append(curl_params)

    numbers = []
    for number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        new_number = number
        numbers.append(new_number)

    return curl_params_list
```

Comment: Please see my answer, does that make sense? I'm new to python, please let me know if I am doing something weird / wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the issue was with line:

```
curl_params = CurlParameters
```

First, CurlParameters class has no **init** function
Second, it should have been

```
curl_params = CurlParameters()
```